# sjplot for Poissson regression with an offset term

Tags: offset, poisson, sjplot

I was wondering if anyone knows whether sjPlot can be used for a Poisson model with an offset term. I tried to do that and I received a message saying that it cannot find the name of offset term.

Any help would be appreciated!
M

Comment: Wich pkg version have you been using? And do you have a small reproducible example?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have been using the latest version, together with ggeffects: library(devtools), devtools::install_github("strengejacke/ggeffects"). It is a wonderful package and everything works for a glmmTMB Poisson model without an offset term. When I include an offset term, I receive an error message saying that the offset variable name was not recognized. I will try and attach a small example (the dataset I have is huge and it includes cross classified random effects) shortly. Thanks!

Comment: model<-glmmTMB(y~logExposure+(1|A)+(1|B), data=mydata, zi=~1,family=poisson)

Comment: Ok, that might be enough information, I probably don't need data - but, how looked your call to `ggpredict()`?

Comment: See examples here: https://strengejacke.wordpress.com/2017/08/27/marginal-effects-for-negative-binomial-mixed-effects-models-glmer-nb-and-glmmtmb-rstats/

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you so much! Yes, I followed the page you suggested and I was able to replicate the examples but only for a Poisson model without an offset term. In my model, I need to account for exposure time, so I included a term for the log of the exposure time. If I run the model above (no predictors, just the offset and the random factors) in ggpredict I get this: Error: `terms` needs to be a character vector with at least one predictor names: one term used for the x-axis, more optional terms as grouping factors.

Comment: Sorry, limited space. When I add a predictor and I run the ggpredict: using this formula ggpredict(mof1, terms = c("visits", "age", "Exposure")) where y=visits, age is the predictor and Exposure is the exposure time I get this:
Error: Column `expy` not found. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me with this!

Comment: I also tried with and without specifying the offset variable "Exposure" in the terms list in ggpredict with the same result above

Comment: I also tried with and without specifying the offset variable "Exposure" in the terms list in ggpredict with the same result above. The model above should have offset(logExposure), I will modify it now- that is the way I specified the model in glmmTMB: this is the formula I actually used:model<-glmmTMB(y~offset(logExposure)+(1|A)+(1|B)

Comment: Ok, it's an issue with the `offset()`-function, that changes the column names in the model frame. I fixed this issue and will commit tonight - the problem should be fixed then. I'll post an answer when the new version is on GitHub...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the error message was because the column name in the model frame still was `offset(logExposure)`, while the functions searched for the cleaned variable name `logExposure`.

Cleaning is done by calling `sjstats::var_names()`, so I fixed this issue there. I had no reproducible example, so I checked with an own model, and the issue was resolved - I hope, this also applies to your use-case.

You should update *sjstats* [from GitHub](https://github.com/strengejacke/sjstats) (`devtools::install_github("strengejacke/sjstats")`), and then *ggeffects* and *sjPlot* should work (if you have the latest package versions from CRAN, and use `plot_model()` from *sjPlot*).

If the variable is named `logExposure`, your call would look like this:

```
# for ggeffects
ggpredict(mof1, terms = c("visits", "age", "logExposure"))
# for sjPlot
plot_model(mof1, type = "pred", terms = c("visits", "age", "logExposure"))
```